# In AWS Aurora's performance insights. What qualifies as "Other" and how do I investigate it?

Tags: postgresql-10, aws-aurora

I have a disproportionate amount of queries that are marked as "Other" in performance insights with no additional details. AWS doesn't seem to provide any details about what this means, and asking on the forum doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to get details about what falls into Other?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Our AWS rep says that "Other" is the sum of all other executing queries. There's also another category called "Unknown" which is queries that AWS hasn't mapped yet.